# How can I know the size of a database in PostgrSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql

I need to know the size of the database to be able to determine the timeout for a dump and determine when I should debug the DB to reduce its size.

Could this scheme work?

```
SELECT table_schema,
ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.tables  WHERE table_schema='DB_NAME'
GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pg_database_size('db_name') / 1048576.0 AS size_in_mb;
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to say in c #

Comment: Works just fine in C#. Just execute that SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size('dbname') );
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to say in c #

Comment: you should call this query to get the return value in c# and work with this value in your code